# How would I save the output of this forloop

Tags: c++, file

This is the code I've already written but I would like to be able to save my for loop output to a file. I have tried using different ways like using ofstream around the loop outside the loop and inside the loop. However even though using these my code runs it does not output information to the file like I would like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct MyStruct {
    int number;
    int numbertwo;
};

void printStruct(MyStruct thestruct);

int main(){
    MyStruct alex[4] = {{15, 20},{30, 35},{45, 50},{60, 65}};

    cout<<"Number"<<"\t"<<"Numbertwo"<<endl;

    int sizeofarray = 4;

    for(int x = 0; x < sizeofarray; x = x+1){
        printStruct(alex[x]);
    }
}

void printStruct(MyStruct thestruct){
    for(int x = 0;x < 1; x++)
     if(thestruct.number > 30){
      cout<<thestruct.number*10<<"\t"<<thestruct.numbertwo<<endl;}
     else if(thestruct.number <= 30){
      cout<<thestruct.number*10<<"\t"<<thestruct.numbertwo<<endl;

}
```

Comment: instantiate ofstream fout; call fout.open('file.ext"); use fout instead of cout. when done, call fout.close()

Comment: Are you able to print "Hello, world!" to a file?

Comment: Yes i can print hello world to a file im just stuck never done it for a for loop

Comment: This is not compiling.  I can't find the definition of `alexisgay`.

Comment: You should pass `thestruct` by `const` reference, e.g. `const MyStruct & thestruct`.

Comment: You don't need the 2nd `if` statement (that follows the `else`).  The `else` clause means all values `<=30` because that is the *opposite* of greater than.

Comment: It's nice that you're happy and want to tell the world about it, but it's also nice to consider that other people may not use words in the same old-fashioned sense as you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a stream parameter to your printing function you can choose where it goes.

```
void printStruct(ostream& os, const MyStruct& thestruct);

int main(){
    MyStruct alex[4] = {{15, 20},{30, 35},{45, 50},{60, 65}};
    int sizeofarray = 4;

    // Print to a file
    ofstream output("results.txt");
    output << "Number" << "\t" << "Numbertwo" << endl;
    for(int x = 0; x < sizeofarray; x = x+1){
        printStruct(output, alex[x]);
    }

    // Print the same to stdout
    cout << "Number" << "\t" << "Numbertwo" << endl;
    for(int x = 0; x < sizeofarray; x = x+1){
        printStruct(cout, alex[x]);
    }

}

void printStruct(ostream& os, const MyStruct& thestruct){
    if(thestruct.number > 30){
        os << thestruct.number*10 << "\t" << thestruct.numbertwo << endl;
    else
        os << thestruct.number*10 << "\t" << thestruct.numbertwo << endl;
}
```